# How to create a new column based on values from other columns in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm new to programming and Pandas. Therefore, please do not judge strictly.

To this table, I need to add a new column of values got from other columns.

```
inp = [{'Date':2003, 'b1':5,'b2':0,'b3':4,'b4':3},{'Date':2003, 'b1':2,'b2':2,'b3':1,'b4':8},{'Date':2004, 'b1':2,'b2':3,'b3':1,'b4':1},{'Date':2004, 'b1':1,'b2':8,'b3':2,'b4':1},{'Date':2005, 'b1':2,'b2':1,'b3':6,'b4':2},{'Date':2006, 'b1':1,'b2':7,'b3':2,'b4':9}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
print (df)

   Date  b1  b2  b3  b4
0  2003   5   0   4   3
1  2003   2   2   1   8
2  2004   2   3   1   1
3  2004   1   8   2   1
4  2005   2   1   6   2
5  2006   1   7   2   9
```

Namely, depending on the date. That is if the value of column `"Date" == 2003` - I need to get the value from column `b1`, if the value of column `"Date" = 2004` then I need to get the value from column `b2`, `"Date" = 2004` - column `b3` and so on. So the values of new column should be: `5,2,3,8,6,9`.

I have a dictionary of correspondences smt. like:

```
Corr_dict = {2003:'b1',2004:'b2',2005:'b4',2006:'b7'...}
```

This is just an example. I have a large dataset, so I want to understand the mechanics.

Sorry for the poor question formatting.
I will be very grateful for any help.

expected output

```
   Date  b1  b2  b3  b4  vals
0  2003   5   0   4   3   5.0
1  2003   2   2   1   8   2.0
2  2004   2   3   1   1   3.0
3  2004   1   8   2   1   8.0
4  2005   2   1   6   2   6.0
5  2006   1   7   2   9   9.0
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use `df.lookup`:

```
df['Correspond'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['Date'].map(dd))
```

MCVE:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

inp = [{'Date':2003, 'b1':5,'b2':0,'b3':4,'b4':3},{'Date':2003, 'b1':2,'b2':2,'b3':1,'b4':8},{'Date':2004, 'b1':2,'b2':3,'b3':1,'b4':1},{'Date':2004, 'b1':1,'b2':8,'b3':2,'b4':1},{'Date':2005, 'b1':2,'b2':1,'b3':6,'b4':2},{'Date':2006, 'b1':1,'b2':7,'b3':2,'b4':9}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)

dd = {2003:'b1', 2004:'b2', 2005:'b3', 2006:'b4'}

df['Correspond'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['Date'].map(dd))
print(df)
```

output:

```
   Date  b1  b2  b3  b4  Correspond
0  2003   5   0   4   3           5
1  2003   2   2   1   8           2
2  2004   2   3   1   1           3
3  2004   1   8   2   1           8
4  2005   2   1   6   2           6
5  2006   1   7   2   9           9
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

I was trying to use your code for my data, but it returns the error:
'One or more column labels was not found'

It seems the problem with the dictionary, but I've checked the column labels several times and it doesn't work. Can I send you my .csv for check? Sorry for the impudence.

Comment: The code I used       


                                        

    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    df = pd.read_csv('Test_Venezuela4.csv')

    dic = {2003_1:'Band_100', 2003_2:'Band_101', 2003_3:'Band_102', 2003_4:'Band_103'}

    df['Correspond'] =  df.lookup(df.index, df['Date'].map(dic))
    print(df)

Comment: Yes.. attach a link to the .csv in comments of this question.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, I would write a function for that:

```
def extract(df, year):
    min_year = df['Date'].min()
    return df.loc[df['Date']==year, df.columns[year+1 - min_year]]

extract(df, 2003)
# 0    5
# 1    2
# Name: b1, dtype: int64
```

And for all year as a colunms:

```
pd.concat(extract(df, year).rename('new_col') for year in df['Date'].unique())
```

Output:

```
0    5
1    2
2    3
3    8
4    6
5    9
Name: new_col, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
s=df.set_index('Date').stack()
df['New']=s[s.index.isin(list(d.items()))].values
```

Answer (score 2):

One would could be using [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), grouping by the `Date` and looking up in `Corr_dict` to keep the corresponding values:

```
melted = df.melt(id_vars='Date')
m = melted.groupby('Date').apply(lambda x: x.variable.eq(Corr_dict[x.name]))
melted.loc[m.values]

    Date variable  value
0   2003       b1      5
1   2003       b1      2
10  2005       b2      1
11  2006       b2      7
19  2003       b4      8
```

Answer (score 1):

if your logic is more complex another method is to use `np.select`

```
import numpy as np

col  = df['Date']

conditions = [(col.eq(2003)), (col.eq(2004)),(col.eq(2005)),(col.eq(2006))]

choices = [df['b1'],df['b2'],df['b3'],df['b4']]

df['vals'] = np.select(conditions,choices,default=np.nan)

print(df)


   Date  b1  b2  b3  b4  vals
0  2003   5   0   4   3   5.0
1  2003   2   2   1   8   2.0
2  2004   2   3   1   1   3.0
3  2004   1   8   2   1   8.0
4  2005   2   1   6   2   6.0
5  2006   1   7   2   9   9.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a straightforward solution to your problem

```
import numpy as np

# initialize the new column
df['b5'] = np.nan
df['b5'] = df['b5'].astype('Int64')

# modifiy your df in-place row by row
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    date = row['Date']
    value = Corr_dict[date]
    df.at[idx, 'b5'] = row[value]
```

Output

```
    Date    b1  b2  b3  b4  b5
0   2003    5   0   4   3   5
1   2003    2   2   1   8   2
2   2004    2   3   1   1   3
3   2004    1   8   2   1   8
4   2005    2   1   6   2   2
5   2006    1   7   2   9   2
```

Answer (score 1):

The other way: use map() method, because you can do some calculations or data changes.

```py
import pandas as pd

dict = {'a' : ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], 'b' : ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

def third_column(param):
    # Here you can do some importans thinks with your new column data. 
    return param + "_created"

df['new_column'] = df['a'].map(third_column)
```

Bye.