# How to add value to new columns depends on the date column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

How to add a new column 'week' in respect to the 'Date' column, showing which week is that date in.
Can I use .loc[] in this kind of situation?

```
week1 = ba.loc['20130901':'20130907']
week2 = ba.loc['20190908':'20130914']
week3 = ba.loc['20190915':'20130921']
week4 = ba.loc['20190922':'20130928']
```

[image]

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61123068/how-to-create-a-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns-in-a-pandas-datafr

Comment: convert your 'Date' column to datetime using e.g. `ba['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ba['Date'])`. then you can get the week number using the [dt accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html), e.g. `ba['Date'].dt.week`.